# TelegramAPI bot

Tags: python, telegram

Please help
What is problem?
Telegram API no connect
Telegram bot no running.
Bot I click to start button, but bot no reply.
main.py

```
telegram import *
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import Responses as R
import Baza as keys

print("Bot baslayir...")

def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Random eleme')

def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Komek lazimdir')

def handle_message(update, context):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response = R.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)

def error(update, context):
    print(f"update {update} caused error {context.error}")

def main():
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

    main()

Baza.py
API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
```

please help.
What to be for connecting?

Comment: first, did you intend to post your API key? If not, then you need to disable it and get a new one quickly. Second, could you please provide more information: what is the expected behavior (in more detail), and what is the actual behavior? If there are errors, please provide those. Finally, did you intend to be calling your `main()` function recursively?

Comment: I to bot start button clicking, but bot no reply

Comment: Because you don't call anything... Your calling line `main()` is ***inside*** the function itself. Un-indent to the global scope

Answer (score 1):

See the final comments in the code below:

```
def main():
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

    main() # this should be outside of your main function scope
main() # Corrected
```